# Repeating a certain method in iOS even when app is in background

Tags: ios, methods, background-process, repeat

I am developing an application that parses some data from web and puts it into a tableview. It is now working only when the user tells the app to do so (by clicking on a certain cell), but I want to change that or rather add a functionality, that would simplify user's life and parse that data (for example) every hour. I was thinking about Local notifications, because that is the only thing I am aware of that runs even when you kill the app. So the question is:

**Is it possible to repeat a certain method or functionality in an app till (for example)the user disables this option? Is there something like a service that is running even when the application is in the background or even killed?**

Can this be done by a local notification? How?

Or what is the appropriate way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something like a service that is running even when the application is in the background

See, for example:

[Running iOS App In The Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758038/running-ios-app-in-the-background)

Your app can run in the background only if it is performing certain permitted kinds of activity.

Comment: So as far as I can get that, there is no way I can get my app running in the background like .. all the time .. I suppose I should make it more .. interactive :) thanks matt

Comment: btw, now I've found this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828762/ios-background-polling-without-location-services) , I had no idea its called polling and what it does, now I get the -1 I had got :-/